# How to reverse extrapolate values $Q$ and $C$ from arithmetic function?

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions, arithmetic-functions

I'm attempting to create a function that causes $Q$ to increase by $1$ whenever $C$ increases by $Q$. The progression of $C$ can be mapped by using $(n/2)*(2Q+(n-1)d)$, where $d = 1$ and $n= Q-9$. What I need from this expression is not the progression of $C$ but a)the value of $Q$, and b) the difference between $C$ and what $C$ needs to be to increment $Q$ by $1$. The Value of $C$ is provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but if the expression were
$$C_n=\frac12d\left(2Q_n+(\color{red}{-}n-1)d\right)$$
I could solve it! Suppose $C_n$ increses by $Q_n$ to become $C_{n+1}$:
$$C_{n+1}=C_n+Q_n\tag{1}$$
Then $Q_n$ increases by $1$:
$$Q_{n+1}=Q_n+1\tag{2}$$
The same thing happens at the next time step so
$$C_{n+2}=C_{n+1}+Q_{n+1}\tag{3}$$
Subtracting eq. $(1)$ from eq. $(3)$ and substituting in eq. $(2)$ we get
$$C_{n+2}-C_{n+1}=C_{n+1}-C_n+Q_{n+1}-Q_n=C_{n+1}-C_n+1$$
Or
$$C_{n+2}-2C_{n+1}+C_n=\Delta^2C_n=1$$
We know how to solve this sort of difference equation:
$$C_n=k_0+k_1n+\frac12n(n+1)\tag{4}$$
Just plug the solution in and check that it works! Then from eq. $(2)$
$$\begin{align}C_{n+1}-C_n&=k_0+k_1(n+1)+\frac12(n+1)(n+2)-k_0-k_1n-\frac12n(n+1)\\
&=k_1+n+1=Q_n\end{align}$$
Now you can see why I wanted that minus sign in there: otherwise for big $n$, $C_n$ would increase like $\frac32n^2$ instead of the $\frac12n^2$ as must be the case as shown in eq. $(4)$. Since we are given
$$n=Q_n-9=k_1+n+1-9=n+k_1-8$$
We can conclude that $k_1=8$ so $Q_n=n+9$ and
$$\begin{align}C_n&=\frac12n(n+1+2k_1)+k_0=\frac12n(n+1+16)+k_0\\
&=\frac12n\left((2Q_n-9)-n+17\right)+k_0=\frac12n(2Q_n-n-1)+k_0\\
&=\frac12n\left(2Q_n+(-n-1)(1)\right)+(0)\end{align}$$
So that fits your pattern with my minus sign, $d=1$ and $k_0=0$.

Now that we have solved the problem, let's go back and answer the question. The value of $Q_n$ is $Q_n=n+9$, really given in the question. Also $C_{n+1}-C_n=Q_n=n+9$, also pretty much given in the question. So I think your question ended up being simple. The more challenging question would have been to get the expression for $C_n$ from the other information.

Comment: For more information, I'm trying to create an automatic character sheet for a role playing game I'm a part of, Legends of the Wulin. There's a resource in the game that starts at 10 and increases by 1 whenever a separate score gains an amount of points equal to that first score. That 10 then becomes an 11 I am trying to find a mathematical way to express this process via 3 numbers; the total amount of points in the second score mentioned above, $C$, the first score above, $Q$, and the difference between $C$ and the next requisite amount of points to increase $Q$. I hope that clarifies, thanks.

Comment: I think my answer covers it then. Your comment doesn't offer an initial value of $C_1$ so if you ever do determine one, then $$C_n=\frac12n(n+17)+C_1-9$$

Comment: $Q_1$ will start at 10 and $C_1$ will start at 0, or at least those are the values given in the game.